# linear algebra linear transformation, $T^2=I$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

$T∈L(V)$. The $T$ composition operator with himself is represented by $T_2$; i.e. $T_2=T∘T$ and for I the operator identity, $I(v)=v$ for all $v∈V$.

If $T_2=I$ and is different---> $±I$

prove that there exists $v∈V∖\{0\}$such that $T(v)=v$

I have done this...

Since $T_2(v)=v$ by the assumptions, we see that $(T−I)(T+I)(v)=0$ for every $v∈V$.

Assume $T(v)≠v$ for every $v∈V∖\{0\}$. We would like to show this is impossible.

Observe that $(T−I)(T+I)(v)=0,∀v∈V$, so $T+I$ sends $V$ to the subspace of $V$ consisting of elements $x$ of $V$ such that $(T−I)(x)=0$, i.e.
$T+I:V→Ker(T−I):=\{x∈V∣(T−I)x=0\}$.
By assumption the RHS subspace is $\{x∈V∣(T−I)x=0\}=\{0\}$.

As a consequence, $(T+I)(v)=0,∀v∈V$. This means that $T=−I$, a contradiction. Therefore $T(v)=v$ for some $v∈V∖\{0\}$.

But in the last steps I have to say.. Why can I confirm this statement...

By assumption the RHS subspace is $\{x∈V∣(T−I)x=0\}=\{0\}$.
 Why does $\{0\}$ is the $x$ value?

Comment: Unlike others, I upvoted your question because it's clear you've put in effort (you should try to format your question  a bit better, look up mathjax). Though I am not sure what you mean by "If T2=I and is different---> ±I". I'm pretty sure you mean $T^2$, and not sure about the arrow implicator

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your solution.
Maybe it's easier to see if you write:
$Ker(T-I)=\{x\in V, (T-I)(x)=0\}=\{x\in V, T(x)-I(x)=0\}=\{x\in V,T(x)-x=0\}=\{x\in V,T(x)=x\}=\{0\}$ 

Because $T(x)=x\iff x=0$.